# Ruby - how to create dynamic model attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, model, attributes

I have an array with model attributes (these model attributes are columns in DB table). I am trying to iterate through this array and automatically create a record which I would like to save to DB table, something like this:

```
columns.each_with_index do |c, i|
  user.c = data[i]
  puts user.c
end
```

`user` is model.
But if I try the snippet above, I get

```
undefined method `c=' for #<User:0x007f8164d1bb80>
```

I've tried also

```
columns.each_with_index do |c, i|
  user."#{c}" = data[i]
  puts user."#{c}"
end
```

But this doesn't work as well.

Data in `columns` array are taken from form that sends user, so I want to save only data that he send me, but I still cannot figure it out...

I would like to ask you for help... thank you in advance!

Comment: which version of rails are you using?

Comment: Is this code in a controller action?  Are you using form_for @user in the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user.send("#{c}=".to_sym, data[i])
```

Also, you can access the attributes as a hash.

```
user.attributes[c] = data[i]
```

Comment: Thanks Marlin for your answer, I am trying it, but getting this error: `undefined method '["0", ""]=' for #<User:0x007f8163eb7080>`

Comment: You don't seem to have an attribute name in the variable c.

Comment: The second version through `attributes` is working me... Thank you Marlin.

Comment: Marlin, this solves problem of `model.attribute`, how could you pass column name into `model[:attribute]`? I've tried a similar way, but error...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing.  The attributes method returns the hash holding the attributes.  user.attributes["--column-name--"] will reference the value of the column and can be set to a new value.

Comment: The columns method in an ActiveRecord class returns an array of Column (class) objects.  The name method on a column object will give the column name.  User.columns[0].name #"id".  If you have a column object named c, then use c.name for the attribute name and follow my earlier advice.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would probably be to build a hash and to use update_attributes:

```
mydata = {}
columns.each_with_index{|c, i| mydata[c] = data[i]}
user.update_attributes(mydata)
```

this way you retain the protections provided by `attr_accessible`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is actually in a controller, you can just make use of some basic rails conventions and build the User record like this:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
  # do something
else
  # render the form again
end
```

Although you can set the values using `send`, I agree with @DaveS that you probably want to protect yourself via `attr_accessible`s.  If your planning to use Rails 4, [here's a good overview](http://rubysource.com/rails-4-quick-look-strong-parameters/).